# If statement in razor with html parts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The following code seems bad arround `|` How to use the `if` statement in razor, with some htmls on the fly ?

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <li>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastUpdate)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Book2.Code)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeOfBook.Label)
    @if(ViewBag.IsAdmin){            
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BookID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.BookID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BookID })
    }
    </li>
 }
```

Comment: Removing the '@' before `if` block should work.

Comment: Thank you but it is not working... It displays the if statement in the browser

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it with `<text>` tag:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <li>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastUpdate)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Book2.Code)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeOfBook.Label)

    @if(ViewBag.IsAdmin){  
        <text>          
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BookID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.BookID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BookID })
        </text>
    }
    </li>
 }
```

Comment: THis worked and seems to be the best approach! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate the beginning of the content with `@:`

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
        ....
        @if(ViewBag.IsAdmin)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BookID }) @:|
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.BookID }) @:|
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BookID })
        }
    </li>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use  **text**  tag

```
@if(ViewBag.IsAdmin){  
    <text>          
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BookID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.BookID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BookID })
    </text>
}
```